# Iconic's ability to support complex web applications

Tags: ionic-framework

Ionic was built with mobile in mind - creating a good mobile experience using web technologies. You start out with a web app, so there is the possibility to use it for all 3 platforms. However I’ve never seen anything that resembles a complex web application that uses iconic for both the web and mobile. Will it support the ability to use 3rd party controls such as complex grid controls that may only be used on the web and not in the mobile apps. I’m trying to decide if we use ionic just for mobile and have a completely separate code base for our web application. Any invites would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Considering looking at this article. https://devdactic.com/ionic-responsive-design/

Comment: If you are planning to develop an "heavy" app, you should have a different code base for the mobile app and for the web application. I already made the mistake to embed web+mobile in one Ionic codebase, and that caused important performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Basically everything that works on the web also works on mobile devices built with Ionic.
Ionic creates a **WebView** where javascript code runs. you can use capacitor or cordova to manage native functionality.

So if you have web developers you can do anything you could do as "Mobile Web" but in an app.

Now you can also choose whether to use react, angular or vue.

For example using Ionic with react you can use the **VirtualDom** and develop exactly as if you were using react on the web.

Instead, using for example **React Native** you will be forced to use a set of react components (or write new ones) but you will not have the VirtualDom available.

However you can also integrate native code, which Ionic doesn't support.

There are a lot of articles online that cover the subject by comparing competitors:

- **[From Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/resources/articles/ionic-vs-react-native-a-comparison-guide)**

So yes, you can use all javascript libraries!